# Issue with the redirection in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I am getting issue with the redirection in Wordpress

If I am trying to open `http://domain.com/about-us` then I am getting blank page. But after that when I am adding "/" after `http://domain.com/about-us/` then it's working perfectly.

But I want `/` to be automatically added in link.

What I have to do for that?

Comment: use javascript window.location=' http://domain.com/about-us/';

Comment: Yes but WordPress have a facility to this type of redirection automatically but unfortunately it's doesn't working in my project.

Comment: Try updating `WP dashboard (Settings > Permalink)` from wp-admin once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check in your permalink settings in the WP dashboard (Settings > Permalink) that you have a forward slash at the end of your permalink structure.